# Factory-girl create that bypasses my model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am using Factory Girl to create two instances in my model/unit test for a Group. I am testing the model to check that a call to .current returns only the 'current' groups according to the  expiry attribute as per below...

```
  describe ".current" do
    let!(:current_group) { FactoryGirl.create(:group, :expiry => Time.now + 1.week) }
    let!(:expired_group) { FactoryGirl.create(:group, :expiry => Time.now - 3.days) }

    specify { Group.current.should == [current_group] }
  end
```

My problem is that I've got validation in the model that checks a new group's expiry is after today's date. This raises the validation failure below.

```
  1) Group.current 
     Failure/Error: let!(:expired_group) { FactoryGirl.create(:group, :expiry => Time.now - 3.days) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Expiry is before todays date
```

Is there a way to forcefully create the Group or get around the validation when creating using Factory Girl?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This isn't very specific to FactoryGirl, but you can always bypass validations when saving models via `save(validate: false)`:

```rb
describe ".current" do
  let!(:current_group) { FactoryGirl.create(:group) }

  let!(:old_group) do
    g = FactoryGirl.build(:group, expiry: Time.now - 3.days)
    g.save(validate: false)
    g
 end
      
 specify { Group.current.should == [current_group] }
end
```

Comment: See Jason Denney's answer below for a better solution.

Comment: since 1.9.1 you can do `g.tap { |g| g.save(validate: false) }`

Answer (score 89):

I prefer this solution from https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/578.

Inside the factory:

```rb
trait :without_validations do
  to_create { |instance| instance.save(validate: false) }
end
```

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than the accepted one.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you did this for your general purpose factory you'd be skipping validations EVERY time you did create on that factory.  It's probably best to use this technique only on a sub-factory (or in a trait).

Comment: You'll almost certainly want to put this in a trait. See the answer by Tim Scott, below.

Answer (score 58):

It's a bad idea to skip validations by default in factory. Some hair will be pulled out finding that.

The nicest way, I think:

```
trait :skip_validate do
  to_create {|instance| instance.save(validate: false)}
end
```

Then in your test:

```
create(:group, :skip_validate, expiry: Time.now + 1.week)
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to all factories?

Answer (score 21):

```rb
foo = build(:foo).tap { |u| u.save(validate: false) }
```

Comment: Nice for the one-off case where you only need this on a single spec

Comment: This is a simple and elegant one-liner in comparison to other clunky answers.

Answer (score 8):

For this specific date-baesd validation case, you could also use the [timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) gem to temporarily alter time to simulate the old record being created in the past.

Answer (score 6):

It is not best to skip all validation of that model.

create `spec/factories/traits.rb` file.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  trait :skip_validate do
    to_create { |instance| instance.save(validate: false) }
  end
end
```

fix spec

```
describe ".current" do
  let!(:current_group) { FactoryGirl.create(:group, :skip_validate, :expiry => Time.now + 1.week) }
  let!(:expired_group) { FactoryGirl.create(:group, :skip_validate, :expiry => Time.now - 3.days) }

  specify { Group.current.should == [current_group] }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your factories should create valid objects by default. I found that [transient attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes) can be used to add conditional logic like this:

```
transient do
  skip_validations false
end

before :create do |instance, evaluator|
  instance.save(validate: false) if evaluator.skip_validations
end
```

In your test:

```
create(:group, skip_validations: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I added an attr_accessor to my model to skip the date check:

```
attr_accessor :skip_date_check
```

Then, in the validation, it will skip if so specified:

```
def check_date_range
  unless skip_date_check
    ... perform check ...
  end
end
```

Then in my factory, I added an option to create an old event:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :event do
    [...whatever...]

    factory :old_event do
      skip_date_check { true }
    end
  end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario you could change validation to happen only on update. Example: `:validates :expire_date, :presence => true, :on => [:update ]`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a FactoryBot `trait` to skip validations *optionally*, as some contending answers suggest, makes sense. An alternative is to stub the model for the specific test case(s) where you don't want validation. This adds a couple of lines of code but is arguably more discoverable. You also have more control over which methods to avoid calling.

Modern RSpec example:

```rb
before(:each) do
  allow_any_instance_of(MyModel).
    to receive(:my_validation_method).
    and_return(nil)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create a custom strategy:

```rb
# spec/support/factory_bot.rb

class SkipValidationStrategy
  def initialize
    @strategy = FactoryBot.strategy_by_name(:build).new
  end

  delegate :association, to: :@strategy

  def result(evaluation)
    @strategy.result(evaluation).tap do |instance|
      instance.save!(validate: false)

      raise "Instance of #{instance.class} is expected to be invalid" if instance.valid?
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.register_strategy(:create_invalid, SkipValidationStrategy)
```

Then in your specs you can use

```rb
let!(:current_group) { create_invalid(:group, expiry: 1.week.since) }
```

See here:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-strategies

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use both [`FactoryBot`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) and [`Timecop`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) with something like:

```rb
trait :expired do
  transient do
    travel_backward_to { 2.days.ago }
  end
  before(:create) do |_instance, evaluator|
    Timecop.travel(evaluator.travel_backward_to)
  end
  after(:create) do
    Timecop.return
  end
end

let!(:expired_group) { FactoryGirl.create(:group, :expired, travel_backward_to: 5.days.ago, expiry: Time.now - 3.days) }
```

**Edit**: Do not update this event after creation or validations will fail.