# After association callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

Help! I'm in a fix .. check it:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    number "1234123412341234"
    exp_month 12
    exp_year 2016

    association :user

    before(:create) do |instance|
      # Start a crypto instance with this users public key and encrypt
      crypt = Modules::Crypto.new(instance.user.encryption_key_id)
      instance.number = crypt.encrypt("1234123412341234")
    end

    trait :unencrypted do
      number "1234123412341234"
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to figure out how to:

1. Trigger a callback *after* the `:user` has been created, but *before* the `:card` has been created (or the Model validations will fail since the card isn't encrypted)
2. Make the `:unencrypted` trait override the callback above.

Comment: Do you have a typo for `instance.card = crypt.encrypt("1234123412341234")`, I think it should be `instance.number = crypt.encrypt("1234123412341234")`

Comment: why not just creating the user yourself in the before(:create) with   `instance.user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)` ?

Comment: @Tony you're right, it's `instance.number`.

Comment: @smallbutton.com would that prevent FactoryGirl from creating another one? Also, how can I get `:unencrypted` to override the callback?

Comment: just leave away the `association :user` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322353/factory-girl-create-that-bypasses-my-model-validation) and this [issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/578) is to change the create method to save without validating. Then, you can add an `after(:create)` that encrypts the value.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :card do
    to_create {|instance| instance.save(validate: false) }
    number "1234123412341234"
    exp_month 12
    exp_year 2016
    user

    after(:create) do |instance|
      # Start a crypto instance with this users public key and encrypt
      crypt = Modules::Crypto.new(instance.user.encryption_key_id)
      instance.number = crypt.encrypt("1234123412341234")
    end

    trait :unencrypted do
      number "1234123412341234"

      after(:create) do |instance|
        # This is a noop to override previous after(:create)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also note that "if the factory name is the same as the association name, the factory name can be left out."